# Vectorizing column wise logical indexing of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

I am doing a column wise logical indexing of a matrix in MATLAB. An example would be :

```
tic

N = 5*10^6;
input = randi(100,N,12);
output = zeros(N,1);

d_sn2 = randi(25,N,12);
d_sd2 = randi(25,N,12);

LL1 = randi(8,N,12);
UL1 = randi([12,20],N,12);

LL2 = randi(8,N,12);
UL2 = randi([12,20],N,12);

for p = 1:N
    temp = zeros(12,12);
    for i = 1:12
        I2 = (d_sn2(:,i)>LL1(p,i) & d_sn2(:,i)<UL1(p,i)) & (d_sd2(:,i)>LL2(p,i) & d_sd2(:,i)<UL2(p,i));
        temp(i,:) = mean(input(I2,:));
    end
    output(p) = max(temp(:));
end

toc
```

I would like to know if I can vectorize this operation or make any faster ?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake. I do use I2 after calculating it. I haven't shown the exact code here due to its size and data involved. but this is the crux of the problem

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I apologize, I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: I have adjusted your code so that all data computed within the inner loop is actually used. I'm not sure this matches what you're trying to do, but it gives me something to discuss in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The computation of `I2` in the inner loop can be easily vectorized. This:

```
temp = zeros(12,12);
for i = 1:12
   I2 = (d_sn2(:,i)>LL1(p,i) & d_sn2(:,i)<UL1(p,i)) & (d_sd2(:,i)>LL2(p,i) & d_sd2(:,i)<UL2(p,i));
   temp(i,:) = mean(input(I2,:));
end
```

is the same as this:

```
I2 = d_sn2>LL1(p,:) & d_sn2<UL1(p,:) & d_sd2>LL2(p,:) & d_sd2<UL2(p,:);
temp = zeros(12,12);
for i = 1:12
   temp(i,:) = mean(input(I2(:,i),:));
end
```

This code uses implicit singleton expansion, if you have a version of MATLAB prior to R2016b, you will need to write each `>` (`gt`) and `<` (`lt`) call using `bsxfun`: `bsxfun(@gt,d_sn2,LL1(p,:))`, etc.

Unfortunately, the indexing into `input` is a lot harder to vectorize. Because every iteration of `i` a different number of elements of `input` are accessed, there is no simple way of creating the matrix `temp` without loops. The few approaches I tried are all much slower than the loop code.

If you are on a fairly recent version of MATLAB, your code will be quite efficient. MATLAB's interpreter uses a JIT (just-in-time compiler) making loops not nearly as slow as they used to be. For example, the difference of a trivial loop to add all elements of a matrix is only 2-3 times slower than using the function `sum`. Back in the old days, this used to be maybe 100 times slower. So the benefits of vectorization are not the same as what they used to be. Coupling that with the very large size of arrays you're using, it means that vectorization is going to be a pessimization, since vectorization often implies creating even larger intermediate matrices.